# Graphql/ gplgen --Golang returning Empty metadata array in response

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

Resolver:

```
func (r *queryResolver) GetProducts(ctx context.Context) ([]*models.Product, error) {
    products := []*models.Product{
        {
            ID:               "1",
            Name:             "Vingate Sofa",
            Image:            "src/assets/images/placeholderimage.png",
            Category:         "Furniture",
            Introductiondate: "2023-05-08",
            Subcategory:      "Sofas",
            Views:            50,
            Metadata: []*models.MetaData{
                {
                    Name:   "Material",
                    Values: []string{"Fabric", "Wood"},
                },
                {
                    Name:   "Color",
                    Values: []string{"Gray", "Black", "Red"},
                },
                {
                    Name:   "Type",
                    Values: []string{"Sleeper", "Sectional"},
                },
                {
                    Name:   "Style",
                    Values: []string{"Contemporary", "Traditional"},
                },
            },
        },
        {
            ID:               "2",
            Name:             "Vintage Table",
            Image:            "src/assets/images/placeholderimage.png",
            Category:         "Furniture",
            Introductiondate: "2023-05-08",
            Subcategory:      "Tables",
            Views:            30,
            Metadata: []*models.MetaData{
                {
                    Name:   "Material",
                    Values: []string{"Wood", "Metal"},
                },
                {
                    Name:   "Color",
                    Values: []string{"Brown", "Black", "Silver"},
                },
                {
                    Name:   "Type",
                    Values: []string{"Coffee", "End", "Console"},
                },
                {
                    Name:   "Style",
                    Values: []string{"Modern", "Rustic"},
                },
            },
        },
    }

    return products, nil
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getAllBlogs": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "image": "https://example.com/blog1.jpg",
                "category": [
                    "Technology",
                    "Productivity"
                ],
                "postdate": "22/3/2024",
                "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus.",
                "views": 100
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "image": "https://example.com/blog2.jpg",
                "category": [
                    "Health",
                    "Fitness"
                ],
                "postdate": "22/3/2024",
                "content": "",
                "views": 200
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Schema:

```
type MetaData {
    name: String!
    values: [String!]!
}

type Product {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    image: String!
    category: String!
    introductiondate: String!
    subcategory: String!
    metadata: [MetaData!]!
    views: Int!
}

input NewMetaData {
    name: String!
    values: [String!]!
}

input NewProduct {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    image: String!
    category: String!
    introductiondate: String!
    subcategory: String!
    metadata: [NewMetaData!]!
    views: Int!
}
```

Golang GplGen returning Empty metadata array in response. Ihave given my resolver, response, Schema parts.
Golang GplGen returning Empty metadata array in response. Ihave given my resolver, response, Schema parts.
Golang GplGen returning Empty metadata array in response. Ihave given my resolver, response, Schema parts.

Comment: Your resolver function seems to be getting product data and the response is getting blog data.

Please provide relevant details to reproduce the issue? Provide Graphql schema that defines the query and Graphql query that retrieves the data.


See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example